# R markdown: How to create a table with images and text which should be knitted as PDF?

Tags: latex, markdown, r-markdown, kable, kableextra

I would like to include a table with 2 columns including images and text (image descriptions) in PDF report compiled with R markdown.
In doing so, I have the following requirements for my table:

- *width:* fixed column or table width
- *alignment:* content alignment in columns

  - top center alignment of an image in column 1
  - top left alignment of text in column 2
- *text content:* is at best easy and good to read also in code
- *text formatting:*

  - text formatting required, at best using markdown syntax, i.e, **bold**
  - linebreaks required
- *image path:* as images are stored in a subdirectory, at best use abbreviated image paths, like

  - `figpath <- "Folder/Subfolder/"` and then
  - `fig1 <- paste0(figpath, "image1.png")`
- *caption:* table caption is required
- *citations:* adding references to the table is required, i.e., like [@R-base]
- *referencing:* the table elsewhere is required

In ideal, the table would look like this:

[image]

I made several attempts based on LaTex syntax, markdown syntax and R markdown syntax (with kable and kableExtra), see MWEs below.
However, none of the approaches yield a satisfying result. 
The LaTex approach comes closest but does not allow to include citations.

The table with images should later be included in a report (thesis) compiled with huskydown, which is related to thesisdown/bookdown. 
Any help is greatly appreciated!

Table below summarizes my approaches, MWEs provided below (for improved LaTex MWE see reply by @samcarter)

[image]

### Latex approach

```
YAML header:
header-includes:
  \usepackage{array}
  \newcolumntype{L}[1]{>{\raggedright\let\newline\\\arraybackslash\hspace{0pt}}m{#1}}
  \newcolumntype{C}[1]{>{\centering\let\newline\\\arraybackslash\hspace{0pt}}m{#1}}
  \newcolumntype{R}[1]{>{\raggedleft\let\newline\\\arraybackslash\hspace{0pt}}m{#1}}


\begin{table}[H]
\centering
\caption{My caption}
\begin{tabular}{@{} C{6cm} L{9cm} @{}}
\\
     \toprule
       Image & Description \\
     \toprule 
      \includegraphics[width=60mm]{Folder/Subfolder/image1.png} &
       \textbf{Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet} [@R-base] \linebreak mauris mauris sollicitudin malesuada amet.\\
      & \\
      \hline
      & \\
      \includegraphics[width=60mm]{Folder/Subfolder/image2.png} &
      \textbf{Lorem ipsum dolor} [@R-bookdown]\linebreak sit amet, mauris mauris sollicitudin malesuada amet. \
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
```

- **Pro:**

  - *vertical alignment:* of column 1 working somehow correctly
  - *caption:* easy to add
  - *text formatting:* linebreaks feasible with "\linebreak" (but does not work so nicely due to block text)
  - generally versatile coding of tables in LaTex
- **Con:**

  - *vertical alignment:* of column 2 not working correctly - ***SOLVED*** for LaTex and simple markdown file ONLY, ***NOT solved for bookdown/thesisdown***
  - *text content:* adding text content to LaTex table is rather ugly
  - *text formatting:* only latex formatting works, i.e. "\textbf{}"
  - Simple markdown text formatting like `**bold**` (obviously) does not work in LaTex table
  - *image path:* can not include abbreviated image paths (**SOLVED**)
  - *citations:* do NOT work in LaTex table - ***NOT solved***
  - *referencing:* how to reference the LaTex table? (**SOLVED**)

### Markdown approach (*NO SOLUTION YET*)

```
Table: Caption of my table
<!-- Table: (\#tab:myTable-reference) Caption of my table -->

| Image | Description |
| :-------: | :----------- |
| ![](Folder/Subfolder/image1.png){#id .class height=50%} | **Image description** [@R-base]  <br/>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, ...          |
| ![](Folder/Subfolder/image2.png){#id .class height=50%} | **Image description** [@R-bookdown] <br/>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, ...           |
|                  |             |
```

- **Pro:**

  - *caption:* easy to add
  - *vertical alignment:* of column 1 working correctly
  - *text formatting:* simple markdown text formatting like `**bold**` works well
  - *citations:* like [@R-bookdown] work well in markdown table
- **Con:**

  - *vertical alignment:* of column 2 not working correctly
  - *text content*: adding text content to markdown table is rather ugly
  - *text formatting:* linebreaks NOT feasible with `<br/>`
  - *image path:* can not include abbreviated image paths
  - *referencing:* how to reference table in simple markdown file? In bookdown one can label the table with `Table: (\#tab:md-table) My caption` and reference it with `\ref{tab:md-table}`. But how about in a simple md file?

### kable approach (*NO SOLUTION YET*)

````
Refer to this table with [foo] or  \@ref(tab:foo)  or \@ref(fig:foo).

(ref:foo-caption) caption
(ref:foo-scaption) short caption

```{r foo, echo=FALSE, out.width='90%', fig.align = "center", fig.cap='(ref:foo-caption)', fig.scap='(ref:foo-scaption)', results='asis'}
library(stringi)
some_text <- stri_rand_lipsum(1)
some_text <- paste("**Image description**", "[@R-bookdown]", "<br/>", some_text)
figpath <- "Folder/Subfolder/"
dat <- data.frame(
  Image = c(
    paste0("![](", figpath, "image1.png){#id .class height=120px}"),
    paste0("![](", figpath, "image2.png){#id .class height=120px}")
  ),
  Description = c(
  some_text, # TEXT IMAGE 1
  some_text  # TEXT IMAGE 2
  )
)
library(knitr)
kable(dat, format = 'pandoc')
```
````

- **Pro:**

  - *vertical alignment:* of column 1 is working correctly
  - *text content:* adding text content to kable table is rather nice
  - *image path:* can include abbreviated image paths
  - *referencing:* easy to reference with label of code chunk
  - easy coding of tables in R markdown; md code of table is nicely structured/readable
  - *text formatting:* simple markdown text formatting like `**bold**` works well
  - *citations:* work well in kable table
- **Con:**

  - *width:* of column 2 far too wide
  - *vertical alignment:* of column 2 not working correctly
  - *text formatting:* linebreaks NOT feasible with `<br/>`
  - *caption:* not working as usual

### kableExtra approach (*NO SOLUTION YET*)

````
Refer to this table with [foo2] or  \@ref(tab:foo2)  or \@ref(fig:foo2).

(ref:foo2-caption) caption
(ref:foo2-scaption) short caption

```{r foo2, echo=FALSE, out.width='90%', fig.align = "center", fig.cap='(ref:foo2-caption)', fig.scap='(ref:foo2-scaption)', results='asis'}
library(kableExtra)
kable(dat) %>%
  kable_styling(full_width = F) %>%
  column_spec(1, width = "30em")
```
````

- **Con:**

  - *width:* of column 2 far too wide
  - *images:* do not show

I am happy to provide an Rmd file with my approaches as well as the generated PDF if of any help.

Comment: See [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60058692/table-in-bookdown-huskydown-with-several-features-citation-caption-url-png-f) for a more refined/detailed version. Any advice is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

For your latex approach:

- vertical alignment: of column 2 not working correctly

  you get your desired alignment by combining a p column (instead of the m column you used) and a top aligned image. For the top aligned image add `\usepackage[export]{adjustbox}` to your header includes and `,valign=t` to the image options
- image path: can not include abbreviated image paths

  Using image paths is easy with `\graphicspath{{./older/Subfolder/}}` in your header includes

other comments:

- using `[H]` as floating specifier is usually not a good idea. This basically guarantees a suboptimal image placement. Instead use `[htbp]` to ensure that latex find the best possible locatiosn for your image.
- don't use `\toprule` within the table, that's what `\midrule` is made for
- don't use `\hline` when you load the `booktabs` package which provides alternatives with superior spacing

---

---

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage[export]{adjustbox}
\newcolumntype{L}[1]{>{\raggedright\arraybackslash}p{#1}}


\graphicspath{{./older/Subfolder/}}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[htbp]
\centering
\caption{My caption}
\label{foo}
\begin{tabular}{@{} L{6cm} L{8.5cm} @{}}
     \toprule
       Image & Description \\
     \midrule 
      \includegraphics[width=60mm,valign=t]{example-image-duck} &
       \textbf{Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet} [@R-base] \linebreak mauris mauris sollicitudin malesuada amet.\\
            \midrule
      \includegraphics[width=60mm,valign=t]{example-image-duck} &
      \textbf{Lorem ipsum dolor} [@R-bookdown]\linebreak sit amet, mauris mauris sollicitudin malesuada amet. \\
      \bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\end{table}

\ref{foo}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your LaTex reprex: graphics path, caption and referencing now work fine! As in https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/272475/citations-in-tabular-environment-not-working/275345 
I tried citing as `\cite{R-base}`. In a simple markdown document, adding `\bibliography{references.bib}` works, but then show [?] in PDF. Compiling the `keep_tex`ed .tex-file with pdflatex did not solve this. Also, adding additionally `\bibliographystyle{apa}` results in error: `! Undefined control sequence. <argument> \protect \astroncite {{R CoreTeam}}{2018}`. Do you have any recommendations?

Comment: The new column alignment works well in a simple markdown file, but not in a report with thesisdown: `,valign=t` yields error 
"tlmgr search --file --global '/biblatex-dm.cfg'
! Package xkeyval Error: `valign' undefined in families `Gin'." 
and adding `\begin{tabular}{@{} L{6cm} L{8.5cm} @{}}`
yields error 
"tlmgr search --file --global '/biblatex-dm.cfg'
! Package array Error:  Illegal pream-token (L): `c' used." Any ideas how to solve?

Comment: @mavericks Can you share a .tex file that reproduces your problems? (I'm not a markdown person, but I could have a look at the problems from the tex side)

Comment: the issue seems to be at the interplay between markdown/bookdown and LaTex, so LaTex does not seem much of the problem here. 
Even for a tabular environment as simple as `\begin{tabular}{@{} c  m{9cm} @{}}` bookdown yields the following error: ! LaTeX Error: Illegal character in array arg.

See the LaTeX manual or LaTeX Companion for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                                                      
l.201 \begin{tabular}{@{} c  m{9cm} @{}}

Comment: @mavericks Can you nevertheless share the .tex file to find out where the problem comes from?

Comment: sure, any advice on how to easiest share the index.tex and index.log with you? many thanks

Comment: @mavericks if the .tex file is too long to add it to your question, you could share it via https://pastebin.com/ or similar services.

Comment: index.tex https://pastebin.com/G3S5zKBL . index.log https://pastebin.com/7sJPXZdm

Comment: @mavericks Thanks. The `array` package seems not to be loaded in your code, this causes the error message

Comment: Thank you for your hint. array package is loaded in the YAML header in the top of the markdown document, see here please: pastebin.com/0HYhqi6v

Comment: @mavericks No idea about the markdown, just that the package is missing from https://pastebin.com/raw/G3S5zKBL

Comment: please see a more elaborate version of this question here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60058692/table-in-bookdown-huskydown-with-several-features-citation-caption-url-png-f/60058693#60058693 many thanks for any help you can provide!